# Run Angular2 app inside Jersey webapp

Tags: angular, typescript, jersey

I have two distinct projects, one for front-end in Angular2 and another one for the backend, in Java with Jersey.

What I want to achieve is to have the front-end app being served by the server that also serves the backend (thus avoiding CORS headers configs).

I am however having a problem when building the angular app with the command `ng build --output-path PATH/TO/WEBAPP-FOLDER`.

When the server is launched and I go to `PATH/TO/WEBAPP-FOLDER/index.html` (where my angular app is started) I got many 404 errors when the browser requests the JS files included in my index page, although my folder structure contains them.

Do I need to do something in Angular configuration so that it can correctly served the JS files?

My webapp folder structure is:

```
-assets/
-favicon.ico
-index.html
-inline.bundle.js
-inline.bundle.js.map
-main.bundle.js
-main.bundle.js.map
-polyfills.bundle.map
-polyfills.bundle.js.map
-styles.bundle.js
-styles.bundle.js.map
-vendor.bundle.js
-vendor.bundle.js.map
-WEB-INF
    web.xml (this is for Jersey)
```

My generated `index.html` page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Also, the `systemjs.config.js` file is nowhere to be found. Am I not running the build command correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using base href in index.html. href in base tag specifies the base URL for all relative URLs in the page. So as you have built with output path "PATH/TO/WEBAPP-FOLDER", you might want to try giving base href="PATH/TO/WEBAPP-FOLDER". This will serve the app from  "domain-name/PATH/TO/WEBAPP-FOLDER".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with Angular (4) and Java/Spring. Similar to OP, to get around CORS setup, I copied my entire Angular app content (from CLI generated folder /my-app), into a new folder called /angular, located at the root of my Java Maven project. I made a custom build file to run

```
ng build --base-href /my-java-project/
```

and then during maven build, used maven-resource-plugin to move the /dist contents from /angular/dist to ${project.build.directory}/my-java-project. By default, angular will try to find resources in the root of your deployment.